# Why does my Mesh disapear when using Softbody physics?

Tags: physics, soft-body

So I have been working on a character in Cycles using Softbody physics and everytime I press ALT+A to check it out the mesh disappears and only the Bones stay playing the animation.

Why? I used Softbody physics in the past in older versions of Blender and I never had this. Is there something new in the latest version I need to toggle? Why does my mesh keep disappearing?

Comment: Are you sure the mesh is parented to the armature ( Select mesh, Shift-Select armature, Ctrl-P, choose automatic weights)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your mesh is parented to the armature in the mesh-objects modifier stack. Seems to work ok in latest version 2.76b[image]